# Bug in PGF data visualization's scaling mapper?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

Take a look at the trivial use of PGF data visualization below,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes,
    visualize as scatter,
    all axes=label
  ]
  data [format = table] {
    x, y
    0, 0
    10, 10
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which would generate

[image]

The problem is when I specify the unit length.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes,
    visualize as scatter,
    all axes=label,
    x axis={unit length=1cm per 2 units} % Unit length manually set
  ]
  data [format = table] {
    x, y
    0, 0
    10, 10
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The unit length is only formally changed, since the scale is equivalent to the default.
But the result is not. Note the difference? The x axis label has moved to around x=1.

What's going on becomes a bit more clear when I put a duplicate y axis with `x axis={goto pos=.5}`, where the axis label should supposedly be.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization [
    scientific axes,
    visualize as scatter,
    all axes=label,
    x axis={unit length=1cm per 2 units}, % Unit length manually set
    y axis={visualize axis={x axis={goto pos=.5}}} % y axis newly drawn
  ]
  data [format = table] {
    x, y
    0, 0
    10, 10
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

So my current guess is a bug in the TikZ library code, specifically one concerning scaling mapper, which `goto pos` seems to refer.
However, I could not investigate further or fix anything since I'm quite illiterate for this kind of code.

I managed to find one more clue that the result of `goto pos` is always **unit length × m** where the unit length is specified as `n per m units`.

So, my question is whether this issue is a simple bug which you can easily fix, or a tricky one.

Comment: Even though some of the developers visit here from time to time, this really isn't the place to add bug reports, http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/ is.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I was aware of the site, but I wanted to confirm this before reporting and hoped someone might have a quick fix before the next update (you know PGF updates quite slow). I thought I summed up my point in the last sentence.

Comment: As I read it, your last sentence essentially says '*is this a small bug or a large bug*', not '*is what I'm seeing a bug?*', or '*how can I circumvent this bug?*'. (Sorry if I'm being very  stupid/silly/nitcpicky/pedantic/whatever.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Don't worry, you're not stupid/.../whatever; I am mostly responsible how you take my words. Anyway thank you for your comment. I'll try taking your advice and improve my question style next time.